# n-fold symbolic integral in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am trying to compute symbolically a n-fold integral (n is a parameter of a function) over, say, the cube [0,a]^n. My code looks like this

```
intCube[n_, a_] := Module[{xvars, range, expression},
xvars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}];
range = Table[{xvars[[i]], 0, a}, {i, 1, n}];
range = Row[Riffle[range, ","]];
Print[range];
expression = Product[xvars[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
Print[expression];
Integrate[expression, range]
];
```

The range and the expression to integrate look both ok, however, I get an awkward result. Any ideas why ?

```
intCube[2, a]

{x1,0,a},{x2,0,a}
x1 x2
x1 x2 Row[{{x1, 0, a}, ",", {x2, 0, a}}]
```

Thanks,

Ion

Comment: Domnule Nechita, the explanation is that `Row` is for formatting (display) only.  Bine ai venit pe Mathematica.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Sequence` to paste in the range in `Integrate` :

```
Remove[intCube]
intCube[n_, a_] := 
Module[{xvars, range, expression}, 
    xvars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}];
    range = Table[{xvars[[i]], 0, a}, {i, 1, n}];
    (* range=Row[Riffle[range,","]]; *)
    Print[range];
    expression = Product[xvars[[i]], {i, 1, n}]; Print[expression]; 
    Integrate[expression, Sequence @@ range]
];

{{x1,0,a},{x2,0,a}}

x1 x2

a^4/4
```

Comment: Thanks mate, works like a charm. I also learned about @@, I am new to mathematica so these tips are useful to me

Comment: @Ion Well, then you can go ahead and change expression using @@

Comment: :) expression = Times @@ xvars; right ?