# Symbolic integration of a indexed product term?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am trying to perform the symbolic integration of the following expression
$$\int \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i | z) p(z) dz$$
where $$p(x_i|z) = \frac{\exp\left(\tfrac{-(x-z)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma_i^2}}$$ and $p(z)$ is also normal. I did search the site and I think that answers to [n-fold symbolic integral in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2948) might be applicable but I really couldn't understand what was going on. Any clues are welcome, Thanks.

UPDATE: I tried to manually compute the integral for product of 3 terms by the following expression 
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{e^{z^2} \left(\sqrt{2 \pi  \sigma _1^2} e^{\frac{\left(x_1-z\right){}^2}{2 \sigma _1^2}}\right) \left(\sqrt{2 \pi  \sigma _3^2} e^{\frac{\left(x_3-z\right){}^2}{2 \sigma _3^2}}\right) \left(\sqrt{2 \pi  \sigma _2^2} e^{\frac{\left(x_2-z\right){}^2}{2 \sigma _2^2}}\right)} \, dz$$

And *Mathematica* produced a pretty bad expression:
$$\tiny\frac{\sigma _1 \sigma _2 \sigma _3 \exp \left(-\frac{\left(\left(2 \sigma _3^2+1\right) \sigma _2^2+\sigma _3^2\right) x_1^2-2 \sigma _2^2 x_3 x_1+\left(\left(2 \sigma _2^2+1\right) \sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2\right) x_3^2-2 x_2 \left(\sigma _1^2 x_3+\sigma _3^2 x_1\right)+\left(\left(2 \sigma _3^2+1\right) \sigma _1^2+\sigma _3^2\right) x_2^2}{2 \left(\left(\left(2 \sigma _3^2+1\right) \sigma _2^2+\sigma _3^2\right) \sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2 \sigma _3^2\right)}\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sigma _1^2 \left(\sigma _2^2 \left(-x_3+2 \sigma _3^2 z+z\right)+\sigma _3^2 \left(z-x_2\right)\right)+\sigma _2^2 \sigma _3^2 \left(z-x_1\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sigma _1 \sigma _2 \sigma _3 \sqrt{\left(\left(2 \sigma _3^2+1\right) \sigma _2^2+\sigma _3^2\right) \sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2 \sigma _3^2}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\sigma _1^2} \sqrt{\sigma _2^2} \sqrt{\sigma _3^2} \sqrt{\left(\left(2 \sigma _3^2+1\right) \sigma _2^2+\sigma _3^2\right) \sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2 \sigma _3^2}}$$

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, note that $\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i | z) p(z) dz$ is also a Gaussian after rearrangement of the terms in the exponent, so you can bypass any such symbolic difficulties by first factoring the integrand, and then doing the single integral of a single Gaussian, which Mathematica can do easily. I'll post an answer in a while.

Comment: Also, could you explain what the `multiple-integral` tag is for? Your expression appears to be the integral over a single variable $z$.

Comment: @DD: Actually I had a more complicated integral in mind but simplified it to the guassian example. I'll remove the multiple integral tag since its not applicable to the simple case that I posted.

Comment: Removed the multiple integral tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can manual expand the symbolic sum with the function `linearExpand` given in my answer to
[How to do algebra on unevaluated integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unsolved-integrals/64447#64447).

```
Clear[linearExpand];
linearExpand[e_, x_, head_] := 
  e //. {op : head[arg_Plus, __] :> Distribute[op], 
    head[arg1_Times, rest__] :> 
     With[{dependencies = Internal`DependsOnQ[#, x] & /@ List @@ arg1},
      Pick[arg1, dependencies, False] head[Pick[arg1, dependencies, True], rest]
      ]};
```

One more difficulty to overcome is that `Sum` is evaluated throughout (perhaps) the integration process.  It really slows things down.  The expansion of the `Sum` results in sums that are constant -- the `z` can be factored out of each sum.  We need to inactivate the sum.  But for some reason [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) does not make the `Sum` [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html), and wrapping the head `Sum` in `Inactive` does not speed up the integration.  So let's resort to manual intervention and replace `Sum` by an inert head `sum`.  Then the integration finishes in a few seconds.

```
exponent = linearExpand[
  MapAt[Apart[#, z] &, Sum[-(z - x[i])^2/(2 σ[i]^2), {i, n}], 1], i, Sum]

ClearAll[sum];
SetAttributes[sum, HoldAll];
With[{int = Exp[exponent /. {Sum -> sum}]},
 Integrate[int, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> (Coefficient[exponent, z^2] < 0 /. Sum -> sum)] /. sum -> Sum
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

First note that since the $p(z)$ and the $p(x_i|z)$ are all Gaussians, the expression can  be rewritten as
$$I=\int \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i | z) p(z) dz=A\int\prod_{i=1}^{2n}\exp\left(-c_i^2(z-z_i)^2\right)=A\int\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}c_i^2(z-z_i)^2\right)\\=A\exp(-d)\int\exp\left(-c_0^2(z-z_0)^2\right)\\=\frac{A\sqrt{\pi}\exp(-d)}{c_0}$$
where the $z_0,c_0,d$ arise from completing the square of the resulting quadratic polynomial $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}c_i^2(z-z_i)^2$. Mathematica can instantly factor such expressions, so this should be fairly easy to implement.

Here's an example, using $A=1,z_i=c_i=i$ and a [code snippet from J.M that completes the square](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23059/9697):

```
$c = Table[i, {i, 10}];
$z = Table[i, {i, 10}];
$s = Sum[$c[[i]]^2 (z - $z[[i]])^2, {i, 10}];
depress[poly_] := depress[poly, First@Variables[poly]]
depress[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := 
 Module[{n = Exponent[poly, x], x0}, 
  x0 = -Coefficient[poly, x, n - 1]/(n Coefficient[poly, x, n]);
  Normal[Series[poly, {x, x0, n}]]]
depress[$s]
```

which produces

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}c_i^2(z-z_i)^2=385 \left(z-\frac{55}{7}\right)^2+\frac{10956}{7}$$

which means that

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{10956}{7}\right)}{\sqrt{385}}$$

which is an astronomically tiny number, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer DD, just one one more clarification though. Could you mention how to symbolically represent a summation of n terms when n is not known beforehand ? I am a mathematica noob and I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: @Pushpendre: I actually don't know how to do that, unfortunately; Mathematica is usually used for manipulating concrete expressions where the terms are provided. Manipulating symbolic sums for arbitrary $n$ is a bit hard to do in Mathematica. Could you give an example of what you would want to do?